# Different values from URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()

Tags: apex, lightning, sandbox, debugging

I have a managed app that uses URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() to create a Remote site for ToolingApi. This works great in all environments (Production, Dev/scratch org), however, it's pretty unreliable in Sandboxes. Sometimes it returns the proper URL sometimes it doesn't.

For example: While running the app in a sandbox, this line of code

`URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()` 
returns https://examplesite--testing.my.salesforce.com

However, using that same method inside Execute anonymous returns
https://exmplesite--testing.cs61.my.salesforce.com which is the correct url needed for the toolingApi.

Anyone have any insight on what could be happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In [Winter 19](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/216/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter19_release_notes.pdf), we will have a new method, `System.Url.getOrgDomainUrl()`, which will always return the correct URL.

> Use the new `System.Url.getOrgDomainUrl()` method to interact with Salesforce REST and SOAP APIs in Apex code. Get
>   endpoints for User Interface API calls, for creating and customizing picklist value sets and custom fields, and more. Use the updated
>   `System.UserInfo.getSessionId()` method to retrieve session IDs, even when your code runs asynchronously.

The `System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()` method is intended to return the host for the current context (e.g. Lightning, Visualforce, Classic UI, Communities). This new method will always return the correct My Domain URL that should be used, and should work correctly with all Sandboxes.

Comment: That function only works if you have My Domain turned on, until hopefully the Winter 20 release when they said they will fix it. (leaving this here to save the next person the hours of banging their head)

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000JWztQAG